# Monero secret key (32b) vs libsodium ed25519 secret key (64b)

Tags: cryptography, privatekey, libsodium

I'm trying to move cryptographic key operations in the [Monero Python module](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-python) from pure Python to `pynacl` which is a wrapper around `libsodium`.

The first problem I stumbled upon is that Monero secret keys are 256 bit (32 bytes) while `nacl.bindings.crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_pk` expects the secret key to be twice as large (64 bytes).

I also see that unclamped scalar is also 64-byte long. Perhaps the reason for key size difference is related to that?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/blob/56f3b9bff23c6e5761a806aaf1222ce5428ddc43/src/nacl/bindings/crypto_sign.py#L175) you can see it's reading the end bytes from the parameter, and as `crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES` is defined ([1](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/blob/f6c17a338702d862be0384c666bbdba3f1fba9e9/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium/crypto_sign.h#L32),[2](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/blob/f6c17a338702d862be0384c666bbdba3f1fba9e9/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium/crypto_sign_ed25519.h#L26)) as 32, only the last 32 bytes of the supplied 64 byte parameter are used.

Comment: This is impressive how hours of looking int the source code may be saved by a simple remark of fellow developer. Thx!